# how to use npm in ansible

Tags: npm, ansible

This is my main.yml file in task:

```yaml
- name: Use npm
  shell: >
        /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 16.16.0"
  become: yes
  become_user: root
- name: Run build-dev
  shell: |
     cd /home/ec2-user/ofiii
     npm install
     npm run build-dev
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  when: platform == "dev"
```

And the output when running the script:

```
fatal: [172.31.200.13]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "cd /home/ec2-user/ofiii\nnpm install\nnpm run build-stag\n",
    "delta": "0:00:00.061363", 
    "end": "2022-11-09 09:45:17.917829", 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 127, 
    "start": "2022-11-09 09:45:17.856466", 
    "stderr": "/bin/sh: line 1: npm：命令找不到\n/bin/sh: line 2: npm：命令找不到", 
    "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: line 1: npm：命令找不到", "/bin/sh: line 2: npm：命令找不到"], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

the error is "npm:command not found" but I am really sure about the installation and the path to be set appropriatelly in the machine, the thing that I doubting is the script

I don't know how to modify my script,I tried to use npm module, but I failed

Comment: Welcome Bob, please use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) when supplying code examples and command output.

Comment: As to your problem, please check the error description after `stderr_lines`, specifically the part with hieroglyphs (i assume chinese). I cannot copy this for translation from the image..

Comment: @Kristian thank you， the error is "npm:command not found"

Comment: Oh, you should add `source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh` in your npm task as well. Each task runs in separate environments and `nvm.sh` is required to set up `$PATH`

Comment: @Kristian thank you for edit code blocks ，your mean is add 「source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh」in 「run build-dev」task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each task environment is separate and you are setting `nvm` environment in a separate task.

The "*Run build-dev*" knows nothing about the paths set up from "*Use npm*"

I'd suggest combining these two tasks, with a few additional changes explained below:

```yaml
- name: Run build-dev
  shell: |
    source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
    nvm use 16.16.0
    npm install
    npm run build-dev
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    chdir: /home/ec2-user/ofiii
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  when: platform == "dev"
```

Additional changes:

1. Using `bash -c "..."` in a shell module would result `/bin/sh -c "/bin/bash -c '...'"`, it's better to use `executable: /bin/bash` instead
2. Shell module has `chdir` argument to specify the directory the script to run at

Check [shell module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) for other arguments and examples.